# Not able to find android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE metadata of contact apps

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-package-managers, android-account, xmlresourceparser

I am trying to get the list of contact writable accounts in my device using the following code

```
        public static final String SYNC_META_DATA = "android.content.SyncAdapter";

    public static final String[] METADATA_CONTACTS_NAMES = new String[] {
            "android.provider.ALTERNATE_CONTACTS_STRUCTURE",
            "android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE"
    };

final Intent intent = new Intent(SYNC_META_DATA).setPackage(resPackageName);
        final List<ResolveInfo> intentServices =
                        pm.queryIntentServices(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if (intentServices != null) {
            for (final ResolveInfo resolveInfo : intentServices) {
                final ServiceInfo serviceInfo = resolveInfo.serviceInfo;
                if (serviceInfo == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (String metadataName : METADATA_CONTACTS_NAMES) {
                    final XmlResourceParser parser = serviceInfo.loadXmlMetaData(
                            pm, metadataName);
                    if (parser != null) {
                        return parser;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but I am always getting XmlResourceParser parser as null. so please help me how can I fetch the list of contact writable accounts in android

Answer (score 0):

There's an API for that, you need to iterate over all SyncAdapters and check if they `supportUploading` and have `ContactsContract.AUTHORITY` as their authority:

```
final SyncAdapterType[] syncs = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType sync : syncs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter: " + sync.accountType);
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals(sync.authority)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SyncAdapter supports contacts: " + sync.accountType + " - supportsUploading=" + sync.supportsUploading());
    }
}
```

`supportsUploading` means that it's a two-way sync, i.e. the user can modify a contact on her device and have the changes synced up to their cloud account.